# How to manage multiple panel layouts for different display setups in KDE?

Tags: kde, kde4, multi-monitor, panel

I use my laptop in 3 display setups:

- laptop only
- laptop + monitor
- laptop + projector

For each one I use different screen setup and panel layout. It's quite boring to modify layout after each display setup change.

As I can use ARandr to create display setups and save them into executable, is there something similar to do same with KDE panels?

Comment: unfortunately, not at this time no. There currently are some people working on kscreen stuff. Don't know if they actually plan on making this happen. I want this feature too. (pretty sure I have a bug open for screen profiles)

Answer (score 0):

If your KDE4 installation doesn't provide `krandr` (or perhaps `KRandRTray` as it was called on KDE3) [you may be screwed](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=119796) until things get better (perhaps with KDE5?).